# Why would an error persist after after uninstalling the module?

Tags: 8, theming

I created a module for Drupal 8 and when I try to add it to the menu it throws this error

```
 Uncaught PHP Exception Twig_Error_Runtime: "An exception has been thrown during the rendering of a template ("Route "hello_world.content" does not exist.") in "core/modules/toolbar/templates/menu--toolbar.html.twig" at line 36."
```

everything fell apart after this.  All of my site was unreachable because of an error page.

I tried removing the module and clearing the cache and the error is still there.  What do I have to do to fix this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is 'normal' as your Twig files are being cached by Drupal. The easiest way to fix the issue is to run `$ drush cache-rebuild` (with Drush 8 which is the only release compatible with Drupal 8) which will handle all cache rebuild, including Twig cache. Alternatively, under `sites/default/files/php` you can safely delete the `twig` directory. If you're not in a multi web server environment, you can delete the `php` directory altogether, which will both delete the Twig cached files and the Service Container.

Comment: I appreciate your help but  what if that doesn't fix it?

Comment: Are you saying it didn't fix it or are you simply willing to determine if there could be alternative approaches?

Comment: nevermind.  I didnt have the right version of drush.  after the right version of drush was installed i got it fixed.